# Как подключить библиотеку с диска к проекту LibGDX на Java?

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

Как добавить библиотеку в проект LibGDX?

Дело в том, что подключение библиотек из mavencentral и тд работает нормально, но если попробовать подключить библиотеку с папки в проекте, то и никакой ошибки не выводиться, но и библиотека не подключается. Я перепробовал уже все варианты, уже во все dependecies в проекте пробовал засовывать implementation files('libs/mylib.jar') и другие варианты этого тоже.

Можно конечно использовать костыль: просто добавить в desktop и core исходники библиотеки, но уж больно мне этот способ не нравится, хотелось бы все-таки разобраться как можно нормально подключить библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым, нужно просто использовать полный путь к библиотеке, вместо локального